# How to flatten a nested JSON data structure into an object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, json

The strings that are coming from source is coming in fragmented JSON object in JSON object.I want to convert this JSON structure to flat JSON structure

```
{
    "nest": {
        "a": {
            "b": {
                "h": {
                    "i": {
                        "all.css": "1",
                        "j": {
                            "k": {
                                "l": {
                                    "lr.png": "2",
                                    "c.png": "3"
                                },
                                ".png": "4"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it but I could only get up to 1 key value pair,
what i want is `{"abhiall.css":"1","abhijkllr.png":"2","abhijklc.png":"3"` ..and so on.
Thanks

Comment: Show us your code and we'll help you fix it.  We can't help you without it.

Comment: This feels more like an assignment question than anything else. If so please try to work it on paper before you start coding would be easier to spot the issue.

Comment: show how you got to the first pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for nested objects.

```js
function flatten(object, target, path) {
    path = path || '';
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            flatten(object[key], target, path + key);
            return;
        }
        target[path + key] = object[key];
    });
}

var data = { nest: { a: { b: { h: { i: { "all.css": "1", j: { k: { l: { "lr.png": "2", "c.png": "3" }, ".png": "4" } } } } } } } },
    flat = {};

flatten(data.nest, flat);
console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user recursive function to return desired result.

```js
var obj = {"nest":{"a":{"b":{"h":{"i":{"all.css":"1","j":{"k":{"l":{"lr.png":"2","c.png":"3"},".png":"4"}}}}}}}}

function flat(data, c) {
  var result = {}
  for(var i in data) {
    if(typeof data[i] == 'string') result[c + i] = data[i]
    if(typeof data[i] == 'object') result = Object.assign(result, flat(data[i], c+= i))
  }
  return result
}


console.log(flat(obj.nest, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

For array of objects I did the following
Note : make sure the Objects Array passed in is n>0 at least

```
flatten(objects, target, path) {
let me = this;    
let retArray = [];
for(let x=0; x < objects.length; x++) {

  let object = objects[x];
  path = path || '';
  target={};

  target = me.flattenHelper(object, target, path);

  retArray.push(target);
}
return retArray;}
```

..

```
flattenHelper(object, target, path){
let me = this;
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log("key : "+ key + " : object : " +  (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') + " path : " + path);
  if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
      me.flattenHelper(object[key], target, path + key);
  }
  target[path + key] = object[key];
  console.log(target);
});
return target;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this function:

```js
const flattenObject = (obj, prefix = '') =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => {
    const pre = prefix.length ? prefix : '';
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') Object.assign(acc, flattenObject(obj[k], pre + k));
    else acc[pre + k] = obj[k];
    return acc;
  }, {});


console.log(flattenObject({"nest": {"a": {"b": {"h": {"i":{"all.css":"1","j": {"k": {"l": {"lr.png": "2","c.png": "3"},".png": "4"}}}}}}}}));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```